# AJAX Post request URL getting weird characters added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to make this cross browser post statement now and I am getting the following error:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://ourdevtest.com/foo/foo",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success:function(result, textStatus, xhr) {
                form.hide();
                console.log('success in preview form');
                console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("xhr: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                app.showThankYou();
            },
            dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
        },
```

Returns a console error of: POST http://%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8B/%E2%80%8Buser:%E2%80%8Bpassword@ourdevtest.com/%E2%80%8Bfoo/%E2%80%8B1/%E2%80%8Bfoo/%E2%80%8B

It cannot load this URL, but I do not know how to stop it from adding strange characters in.

Comment: %E2%80%8b is the url-encoded byteform of `â`... odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you decode that error response, you have this string: *http://​/​/​user:​password@ourdevtest.com/​foo/​1/​foo/*​

I think you should try use some fields values directly, istead of using form.serialize(), just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

first of all remove

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
```

form your ajax call

and try

```
success:function(result, textStatus, xhr) {
      alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));              
}
```